# how create a new git repo whose first commit is the last commit of the source (no history, not linked to source repo, and only the master branch)

Tags: git

How do I create a clone of a git repo that contains only the master branch, and only the most recent commit, AND can be pushed to a new repo at github/bitbucket/etc?

I've got a large git repo... couple of GB... that grew over a decade... lots of obsolete binary cruft... lots of old branches. That's the current legacy app.

We're creating a new app and want to create a new repo that contains only the current commit and the master branch.

I thought maybe I should do some sort of shallow clone like `git clone --depth [depth] [remote-url]` but

a) I'm not sure how to also not include any branches except master?

b) more importantly, the problem with `git clone --depth` is it creates some kind of 'grafted' commit, which cannot then be pushed to github (the "shallow update not allowed" issue).

I should mention, in this case, I have the legacy repo on the same computer, in case the "right answer is to simply copy the project folder and trash the .git folder. But I'm hoping as a more general solution that there's git-way to do it.

Comment: If you want the code without its history, why not just recreate a repo from current source? Just `git init` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in case the right answer is to simply copy the project folder and trash the .git folder.

In your case I believe starting with a new fresh repo with the latest state of the files **is** the "best" answer. You really don't gain much by doing anything else. Besides, you'll probably want to re-write the most recent commit message anyway; having your first commit in the new repo say "Fix bug in thing X" wouldn't be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Create an orphan branch from the head of the current `master`.

```
git checkout --orphan foo master
git commit
```

Push `foo` to the new repository.

```
git push <url_to_new_repo> foo:refs/heads/bar
```

As you mentioned a lot of binaries, I suggest you use `git lfs` to track them.